# how to access template script variable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having scripts to implement whiteboard using canvas within  tags in template page of angularjs. Now i want to assign points[] variable value to angularjs scope variable.

```
<script>
var points = [];
</script>
```

how to access this points in angular js controller.

```
scope.ponts = ponints;
```

Comment: typo scope.points = points; :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $window service to get the variable:-

```
var points = ['1','2'];

var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.point= $window.points ;
}]);
```

plunker:- http://plnkr.co/edit/FzybyOZKiLvHuaMaYCuJ?p=preview

Comment: This answer won't work because it wasn't assigned to the window, and is overkill if they know when everything is going to be loaded

Comment: i have added the plunker.

Comment: @PeterAshwell This is not overkill. The controller is far easier to test when accessing `points` through a dependency injection. This approach should be encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it in your controller as it is in the global scope.

See this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/G8RQKe6tK48mWXpsl9ov?p=preview

```
<script>
  var points = [];
</script>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Points: {{data}}</p>
</body>

</html>
```

and app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = points;
});
```